# Automatically refactor string concatenation to string substitution?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm faced with a *really ugly* code that is a code generator, that takes a configuration file and outputs C code.
It works, but the script is full of things like:

```
outstr = "if(" + mytype + " == " + otherType + "){\n"
outstr += "    call_" + fun_for_type(mytype) + "();\n"
outstr += "}\n"
# Now imagine 1000 times more lines like the previous ones...
```

Is there a tool to automatically change code like that to something more palatable (partial changes are more than welcome)? Like:

```
outstr = """if ({type} == {otherType}) {
    call_{fun_for_type}({type});
}
""".format(type=mytype, otherType=otherType, fun_for_type=(mytype))
```

If this would have been C then I would have abused of Coccinelle, but I don't know of similar tools for Python.

Thanks

Comment: Please rephrase the question to not ask for a tool, but for better ways to approach the problem. Otherwise, it might be quickly closed as "asking for a software, tool"..

Answer (score -2):

You can use dictionaries :

```
datas = {"type":mytype, "otherType":otherType, "fun_for_type":(mytype)}
outstr = "if ({type} == {otherType}) {{\n\
          call_{fun_for_type}({type});\n\
          }}\n".format(**datas)
```

Comment: That still requires making manual changes to the code. The OP is asking how to automate the process.